# Finding combinations of elements in a list based on routing

Tags: python-3.x, list, pattern-matching

I'm not sure how to verbally express what I want to achieve, and formulating a proper question for this, so here's an example:

If I have a comprehensive list with elements like this:

```
list = ['A to B', 'B to C', 'C to D', 'D to E', 'A to C', 'A to D', 'A to E',
 'B to A', 'B to C', 'B to D', 'B to E', 'C to A', 'E to B', 'E to C', 'E to A']
```

I would like to find all unique combinations of exactly 3 elements expressing a routing, and subsequently, store those combinations in separate lists like so:

```
['A to B', 'B to C', 'C to A'],

['B to C', 'C to A', 'A to B'],

etc.
```

So, in the first example output, A reverts back to A, and in the second output, B reverts back to B. I would like to see anything reverting back to itself in this fashion.

I'm new to Python and trying to think of ways to do this, but I get stuck.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using permutations from itertools maybe not the best choice but it gives the result as you wanted

```
#importing permutations from itertools
from itertools import permutations as c
lst= ['A to B', 'B to C', 'C to D', 'D to E', 'A to C', 'A to D', 'A to E',
 'B to A', 'B to C', 'B to D', 'B to E', 'C to A', 'E to B', 'E to C', 'E to A']
#permutation of the list with r as 3
lst_com = c(lst,3)
# this list is to reduce redundancy
d=[]
for i in lst_com:
    t=list(i)
    # if statement to check the express routing and not include redundant values
    if t[0][0] == t[2][-1] and t[0][-1] == t[1][0] and t[1][-1]==t[2][0] and t not in d:
        d.append(t)
        print(t)
```

Output :

```
['A to B', 'B to C', 'C to A']
['A to B', 'B to E', 'E to A']
['B to C', 'C to A', 'A to B']
['C to D', 'D to E', 'E to C']
['D to E', 'E to B', 'B to D']
['D to E', 'E to C', 'C to D']
['D to E', 'E to A', 'A to D']
['A to D', 'D to E', 'E to A']
['A to E', 'E to B', 'B to A']
['A to E', 'E to C', 'C to A']
['B to A', 'A to E', 'E to B']
['B to D', 'D to E', 'E to B']
['B to E', 'E to A', 'A to B']
['C to A', 'A to B', 'B to C']
['C to A', 'A to E', 'E to C']
['E to B', 'B to A', 'A to E']
['E to B', 'B to D', 'D to E']
['E to C', 'C to D', 'D to E']
['E to C', 'C to A', 'A to E']
['E to A', 'A to B', 'B to E']
['E to A', 'A to D', 'D to E']
```

Comment: Thanks! I have 810 elements in my list, however. Got a memory Error. Is there a way to evaluate the conditions during the permutation function, and only store the necessary? Or another elegant way to not run into memory problems?

Comment: will you provide the list?

Comment: I've got it done, split the dataset in logical smaller pieces.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting all steps into a dictionary of `key -> list of keys`  it leads to.

You can query this to get all the triplets:

```
data = ['A to B', 'B to C', 'C to D', 'D to E', 'A to C', 'A to D', 'A to E',
 'B to A', 'B to C', 'B to D', 'B to E', 'C to A', 'E to B', 'E to C', 'E to A']

from collections import defaultdict
routes = defaultdict(list)

for d in data:
    frm, to = d.split(" to ")
    routes[frm].append(to)

print (routes)

plets = set()

for frm, to in routes.items():
    for target in to:
        for target2 in routes[target]:
            if frm in routes[target2]: 
                plets.add( (frm, target, target2, frm) )

for t in sorted(plets):
    print(*t, sep= " -> ")
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
                             'B': ['C', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
                             'C': ['D', 'A'], 
                             'D': ['E'], 
                             'E': ['B', 'C', 'A']})

A -> B -> C -> A
A -> B -> E -> A
A -> D -> E -> A
A -> E -> B -> A
A -> E -> C -> A
B -> A -> E -> B
B -> C -> A -> B
B -> D -> E -> B
B -> E -> A -> B
C -> A -> B -> C
C -> A -> E -> C
C -> D -> E -> C
D -> E -> A -> D
D -> E -> B -> D
D -> E -> C -> D
E -> A -> B -> E
E -> A -> D -> E
E -> B -> A -> E
E -> B -> D -> E
E -> C -> A -> E
E -> C -> D -> E
```

Using a set to store your possible routes avoids getting same ones multiple times.

---

Edit for outputting issue:

```
def formIt(a,b,c,d):
    return f"{a} to {b}",f"{b} to {c}",f"{c} to {d}"

for frm, to in routes.items():
    for target in to:
        for target2 in routes[target]:
            if frm in routes[target2]: 
                plets.add( formIt(frm, target, target2, frm) )

for t in sorted(plets):
    print(*t, sep = ", ")
```

to get

```
A to B, B to C, C to A 
A to B, B to E, E to A 
A to D, D to E, E to A 
 ... snipp...
E to C, C to A, A to E 
E to C, C to D, D to E
```

Comment: I like the solution, but I need to keep it being "A to B", "B to C" etc. explicitly. I'll see if I can still apply this code, because intuitively it seems that working with dictionaries could work around the memory error I get from TonyStark's solution.

Comment: @Mighty you can recreate your input from the data - see edit. ... and editted again.